# event_start always returning contact number in android

Tags: java, android, contacts, android-contacts, android-cursor

Why `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE` always returning contact number. The number is available in Google Contacts.

[image]

[image]

Here what I am doing...

```java
Cursor c;
        if (contactID=="") {
            c = activity.getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");
        }else{
            StringBuffer whereClause = new StringBuffer();
            whereClause.append(Phone.CONTACT_ID);
            whereClause.append("=");
            whereClause.append(contactID);
            c = activity.getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, whereClause.toString(), null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");
        }
birthday = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE));
```

For setting in layout.

```java
birthday = fetchSpecificContact.get(Constants.BIRTHDAY);
etxtBirthday.setText(birthday);
```

I can't see any problem anywhere. API level 22 maybe. Android version : 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is running on the `Phone.CONTENT_URI` table, which can only return basic Contacts table columns + Phone specific columns, it can't for example return `Event.START_DATE` data.

The `Phone.Number` constant and the `Event.START_DATE` constant both map to the underling field `ContactsContract.DataColumns.DATA1` (see [Phone columns here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone)) - that is why you're getting the phone number in your code.

To get information from multiple contact data tables you need to query on `Data.CONTENT_URI` table instead, which will return data from **all data types** and then use the mimetype value to figure out which type of row you are currently on.

So if you need only Phone and Event data types, here's the code:

```
String[] projection = {Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1}; // if you need more fields add them here

// query only phones / events
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1); // full name
    String mime = cur.getString(2); // type of data (phone / event)
    String data = cur.getString(3); // the actual info

    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + "-" + name + "-" + mime + ": " + data);

    if (mime == Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE) {
        // do something with the phone
    } else {
        // do something with the event start_date
    }
}
```